How to migrate the NCWidgetProviding to WidgetKit in Objective-C iOS app
I need to migrate the NCWidgetProviding to WidgetKit, because the widget is not working in the iOS latest version like 18.1 and other versions.
How to migrate this in Objective-C

The only way is to implement new widget with SwiftUI. You will bet even not able to use UIViewRepresentable.
